# No module named 'scikitlearn' while in conda list already

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, anaconda

When I want to `import scikitlearn` in Jupyter Notebook.

It showed ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scikitlearn'

What I have done is the following :

- I installed anaconda 3 correctly.
- I have opened open an virtual environment, `$ conda create -n py364 python=3.6.4`
- I have activated the environment by `$ source activate py364`
- I have installed scikitlearn by `$ conda install scikit-learn`
- From the `$ conda list`, I can see it's installed as below output

**# packages in environment at /Users/galaxylam/anaconda3/envs/py364a:

**# Name , Version ,  Build,  Channel

**# scikit-learn , 0.19.1 , py36hffbff8c_0

I also tried `pip3 install sklearn` and `pip install sklearn` under the virtual environment. It showed : Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in ./anaconda3/envs/py364a/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from sklearn).

However, I still can't import scikitlearn, could you please help? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be importing it wrong. Have you tried:

```
import sklearn
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It's ok now.